# Access a list of dataframes and transform values from columns with only two uniques values in binaries ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, types

I have a List of Dataframes (`qlst`) and I want to access every column from every dataframe that have only 2 unique row values and transform all nan values in zeros and all string values in 1s.

I tried to create a function binary to do so:

```
def binary(x):
  '''
  make all values binary by transforming all nan values in 0s and all str in 1s
  '''

  for df in x: #accessing dataframes in qlst
    for column in df:  # accessing columns in dataframe
      qarray = df[column].unique() #transforming unique values in array
      for i in qarray: 
        if len(qarray) == 2: # selecting all arrays with only 2 unique values
          df[column] = df[column].fillna(0) #filling nan values with zero
          if type(i) == str:
            i=1

            return x

binary(qlst)
```

Only the zero values are working! This won't return the 1 values that I wanted.

Example of output:

```
qlst[20]
```

> ```
> Q42AvaliouMarca03
> 0     0
> 1     Marca03
> 2     0
> 3     Marca03
> 4     0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve your objective of:

> transform all nan values in zeros and all string values in 1s.

(Suppose what you refer to as `'all string values'` means non-NaN values)

```
df[column] = df[column].notna().astype(int)    # set NaN to 0's and non-NaN to 1's
```

Here, we check the column values of `column` with [`.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) (`Not null`). It returns `True` (integer equivalent of `1`) when Non-NaN and `False` (integer equivalent of `0`) when `NaN`.  Then, we use [`astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to turn the boolean values to the equivalent integer values.  Thus, achieving your object.

Putting back into your codes:

```
def binary(x):
  '''
  make all values binary by transforming all nan values in 0s and all str in 1s
  '''

  for df in x: #accessing dataframes in qlst
    for column in df:  # accessing columns in dataframe
      qarray = df[column].unique() #transforming unique values in array
      for i in qarray: 
        if len(qarray) == 2: # selecting all arrays with only 2 unique values
          df[column] = df[column].notna().astype(int)    # set NaN to 0's and non-NaN to 1's

            return x

binary(qlst)
```

Comment: @CarolVieira  What result you get ?

Comment: It's not giving me any error, it just don't change any values on the dataset